# Does a user profile using profile2 work with the metatags module?

Tags: meta-tags, 7, users

I am using the **profile2 module**. I am looking for a way to set my meta tags based on user profile type. For example, I have teachers, students, and parents as profile types and each of their profiles have unique content. I would like the meta tags to be based on tokens so that they are unique for each profile.

I have tried the **metatags module** but I can not get the tags to be specific to the profile type (it does give you that option, though). So far I can only get unique meta tags on the user which means all profiles and users have the same token set, so that is a no go.

Any suggestions how to get this to work with metatags module or another way would be helpful. I hope this site produces better results than what I am getting on Drupal issue boards.

Edit:
I have posted a similar question on the drupal issue board. I hope that does not disqualify my bigger question here of "how do I get custom token based meta tags on my various profile types".

Drupal 7

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as outdated and/or inactive. Furthermore this definitively is more of a feature request issue to Metatag tracked on drupal.org.